# Getting "Error 1706. An installation package for the product Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 1033 Lang Pack cannot be found"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, installation

I am getting below error while installing SharePoint server 2010:

Product: Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 1033 Lang Pack -- Error 1706. An installation package for the product Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 1033 Lang Pack cannot be found. Try the installation again using a valid copy of the installation package 'wssmui.msi'.

I am trying to resolve it since 2 days but no success yet.Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: What operating system are you trying to install on? (Have posted this as an answer as I don't have permission to write comments)

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Installation completed after formation of machine.